# OpenMP code is aborted

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

I'm trying to perform matrix multiplication using openMP as follows and I compile it using GCC : `g++ -std=gnu++11 -g -Wall -fopenmp -o parallel_not_opt parallel_not_opt.cpp`

But when I try to run it by using `parallel_not_opt.exe`, it aborts giving the typical Windows error **parallel_not_opt.exe has stopped working...**

Am I missing something?

```
#include "includes/stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
# include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cfloat>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;


//populate matrix with random values.
double** generateMatrix(int n){ 
    double max = DBL_MAX;
    double min = DBL_MIN;
    double** matA = new double*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matA[i] = new double[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            double randVal = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            matA[i][j] = min + randVal * (max - min);
        }
    }
    return matA;
}

//generate matrix for final result.
double** generateMatrixFinal(int n){ 
    double** matA = new double*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matA[i] = new double[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matA[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return matA;
}

//matrix multiplication - parallel
double matrixMultiplicationParallel(double** A, double** B, double** C, int n){
    int i, j, k;
    clock_t begin_time = clock(); 
# pragma omp parallel shared ( A,B,C,n  ) // private ( i, j, k )
    {
# pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            //            cout<< i << ", " ;
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    double t = float(clock() - begin_time); 
    return t;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    ofstream out("output.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    out << "--------------STARTED--------------" << "\n";
    int start = 200, stop = 2000, step = 200;

    for (int n = start; n <= stop; n += step)
    {

        srand(time(NULL));
        cout << "\nn: " << n << "\n"; 
        double t1 = 0;

        int my_size = n; 
        double **A = generateMatrix(my_size); 
        double **B = generateMatrix(my_size); 
        double **C = generateMatrixFinal(my_size); 
        double single_sample_time = matrixMultiplicationParallel(A, B, C, n);     
        t1 += single_sample_time;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            delete[] A[i];
            delete[] B[i];
            delete[] C[i];
        }
        delete[] A;
        delete[] B;
        delete[] C;         
    }
    out << "-----------FINISHED-----------------" << "\n";
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and pinpoint the error. It is hard to find the error without debugging it. And one more thing, check whether your compiler supports openMP. Not all compilers implement openMP.

Comment: @ShanilFernando But it runs correctly in Visual Studio, I'm trying to run it using CMD and get this error.

Comment: Did compile it to release? Visual studio compiler is not gcc by default

Comment: @ShanilFernando `gcc -v` gave me `--enable-libgomp` and I assumed openMP is enabled, am I right? And it runs correctly in VS in both release and debug modes.

Comment: Are you familiar with gdb? Use it and debug or wait for few hours until i go back home and help you to debug it.

Comment: @ShanilFernando Zulan's solution works and now I understand what was wrong.

Comment: I saw his answer. I'm glad that you found the bug, Anyway I really admire someone from my country using openmp. I have a one recommendation for you, try to implement matrix calculations with CUDA (GPU accelerated). you will be amazed how much performance gain you can achieve. Specially for real time applications with more than 5,000,000 matrix calculations per second is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `private ( i, j, k )` declaration is not optional. Add it back, otherwise the inner loop variables `j` and `k` are shared, which completely messes up the inner loops.

It is better to declare variables as locally as possible. That makes reasoning about OpenMP code much easier:

```
clock_t begin_time = clock(); 
# pragma omp parallel
{
# pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
} 
return float(clock() - begin_time);
```

In that case, `A,B,C` will be shared by default  - coming from the outside, and `j,k` are private because they are declared within the parallel scope. The loop variable of a `parallel for` is always implicitly private.